# Break out of foreach loop php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a script which prints out messages from within a database.

Each message is written by a different user.

What I would like is for only users who are friends with the message creator, be able to view the message.

The script I have is:

```
foreach($updatesarray as $data)
 {
 $qu=mysql_query("SELECT frid FROM friends WHERE usid='$uid'")or die(mysql_error());
 $dataq=array();
 $qurow=mysql_fetch_array($qu);
 $dataq[]=$qurow['frid'];
foreach($dataq as $value){
  if($value!=$data['uid_fk'])
    continue;
}

/ Continues the output of the message
```

The first foreach takes the data from the mysql query array.
Then within that foreach I perform another mysql query to identify the list of friends for the currently logged in user. I put the results into an array and create a new foreach. If any of the loops are found *NOT* to be a user, it will then continue... But it isn't continuing how I would like it to. I need it to skip the whole output of the message, instead of continuing the second foreach.

The variable $data['uid_fk'] is the message creator stored in the database.

Database query:

```
if($viewtype=="friends"){
         $viewquery="M.uid_fk=U.uid";
         $query = mysql_query("SELECT M.msg_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.created,       U.username, U.firstname, U.middlename, U.surname, M.uploads FROM messages M, users U  WHERE     $viewquery $morequery order by M.msg_id desc limit " .$this->perpage) or     die(mysql_error());

        }
```

Comment: I suggest you solve that with your query already, to only return updates of friends instead of all updates that need to be filtered within PHP.

Comment: let me get this straight.  you need to break out of the 2nd for loop?  If you need to `break` out of it, use the keyword `break`.  I am not trying to be sassy, i may be miss reading it, could you please specify the question better!

Comment: Sorry Michael, not break out as such, I need to "skip" the current loop and continue with the rest of the foreach loops.

hakre, I will add my query code up in a minute, as I am unsure how I would go about doing it through the query. I did try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to join messages and friends tables in query, and in one shot you have both.

Comment: I was trying to do this earlier, but I couldn't figure out how to take the array from the friends table and then use it in the messages query. For instance, what if a user has 1000 friends?

Answer (score 1):

Set a flag when you `continue`, if this flag is set -> don't output the message.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean when you say set a flag. Could you  offer a bit more advice regarding this please? Thank you

Comment: Setting a variable to some value that you later check. Which PHP book are you using?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I haven't used a PHP book in my life, picked it all up as I have been going along for the last 8 years

Comment: @TelfordComputer-DoctorLtd: Sorry to hear that. It does explain why you don't know how to use a variable for flow control after eight years, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to skip your first loop:

`continue 2;`

This `2` parameter controls which of the nested loops will continue.

Comment: yikes.. i did not realize the amount of goto control one had in php.

Comment: I have just tried this and it is missing alot of messages out, including ones created by the user themselves.

Comment: @Michael: Why's that? This feature is clearly documented on http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: @TelfordComputer-DoctorLtd: Then you did something else wrong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i usually take the approach of learn when needed.  I learned here.  I do not know if i like it, but i learned non the less.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 
`foreach($updatesarray as $data)
 {
 $qu=mysql_query("SELECT frid FROM friends WHERE usid='$uid'")or die(mysql_error());
 $dataq=array();
 $qurow=mysql_fetch_array($qu);
 $dataq[]=$qurow['frid'];
 foreach($dataq as $value){
  if($value!=$data['uid_fk'])
 continue 2;
}`

Comment: @TelfordComputer-DoctorLtd: I'm not going to decode that. Make a stripped-down testcase